# How do I show Paging in a dynamic tablelayout?

Tags: android

In my application I am getting data from server and showing it using a table layout some times I am getting a data of atleast 20 to 30 rows but I want to show 4 rows at a time and then I want to show another 4 etc.

For this I want to know how can we use paging (Previous/Next) in Android if it's not possible with tablelayout can any one suggest which field can give that facility I aleady tried with **GridView** also but no luck

Comment: My opinion for this problem will be using List . As you can have Lazy Loading concept in List view.

Please share your need for pagination.

Comment: But i need to show 6 columns in a row and also two columns are edit fields in that row, i don't think listfield is an option

Comment: You can design cell layout as needed by you and you can inflate this in List.

Comment: ok i am explaining my need clerly,actually i am getting data from server using JSON i am not storing the data directly from arraylist i am getting it and displaying in a table row but in some situation there is a chance of 30 rows but my client needs he don't need any scrolling option if i use list scroll will come so it's not preferred if possible can u give idea any refresh options for this without using paging

Comment: Have you tried using AsynTask. You can use onPostExecute method to render the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way ...

Store parsed data in List(or whatever) and create a method say createRows() which takes list as its argument and using list create rows.

So from your main list (parsed data list) create a sublist of size 4 and pass it to method. So initially it will create table with 4 row (as your requirement).

And on your next button first remove table's current rows using removeAllViews() method and then extract another sublist containing next 4 data to be shown & again pass it to createRows() method.So now it will create table with new data.

Same thing can be applied to previous button.

Answer (score 0):

> you can do it with fragments, there will be two fragments one will contain buttons(prev/next) or other fixed position data. and the other fragment will dynamically load data on request of button if you can program it.