# Implementing pagination in android with tablelayout

Tags: java, android

I have a table layout where rows are dynamically added. I want 30 data to be shown in one page.pages should be automatically added with increasing data. This is my code.

```
 int increment = 0;
public int TOTAL_LIST_ITEMS;
public int NUM_ITEMS_PAGE = 50;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_tab1, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    tableLayout = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tableLay);
    buttonNext = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.next);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);

    buttonPrev = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.prev);


    buttonPrev.setEnabled(false);
  //  data = new ArrayList<String>();


    buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            increment++;
            loadList(increment);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"the page is"+increment,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            checkEnable();
        }
    });

    buttonPrev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            increment--;
            loadList(increment);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"the page is"+increment,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            checkEnable();
        }
    });


    db = getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase("hitechData.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    DBHelper dh = new DBHelper(getActivity(), "hitechData.db", null, 1);

    tableLayout.setColumnStretchable(0, true);
    tableLayout.setColumnStretchable(2, true);
    tableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
    tableLayout.bringToFront();
    db = getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase("hitechData.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
    db.setVersion(1);
    db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    dh.onCreate(db);
    db.setLockingEnabled(true);
    String query = "SELECT * FROM leadData3 Order by id DESC";

    Cursor cur;
    cur = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    TOTAL_LIST_ITEMS = cur.getCount();
    data=TOTAL_LIST_ITEMS;

    int val = TOTAL_LIST_ITEMS % NUM_ITEMS_PAGE;
    val = val == 0?0:1;
    pageCount = TOTAL_LIST_ITEMS / NUM_ITEMS_PAGE;


    if (cur != null && cur.getCount() > 0) {
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            try {

                while (cur.isAfterLast() == false ){
                    TableRow tr = new TableRow(getActivity().getBaseContext());

                    final TextView compName = new TextView(getActivity().getBaseContext());
                    compName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.borderr);

                    final TextView firstName = new TextView(getActivity().getBaseContext());
                    firstName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.borderr);

                    final TextView midName = new TextView(getActivity().getBaseContext());
                    midName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.borderr);

                    final TextView lastName = new TextView(getActivity().getBaseContext());
                    lastName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.borderr);

                    compName.append(cur.getString(1));
                    compName.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                    compName.setPadding(30, 0, 0, 0);


                    firstName.append(cur.getString(21));
                    firstName.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                    firstName.setPadding(30, 0, 0, 0);

                    midName.append(cur.getString(22));
                    midName.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                    midName.setPadding(30, 0, 0, 0);

                    lastName.append(cur.getString(23));
                    lastName.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                    lastName.setPadding(30, 0, 0, 0);

                    // String name =firstName.getText().toString()+midName.getText().toString()+lastName.getText().toString();

                    firstName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            String nameValue = firstName.getText().toString();
                            String companyValue = compName.getText().toString();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ShowDetailData.class);
                            intent.putExtra("name", nameValue);
                            intent.putExtra("accNo", companyValue);
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), nameValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });


                    tr.addView(firstName);
                    tr.addView(compName);

                    tableLayout.addView(tr);
                    cur.moveToNext();

                   /* count++;
                    nextPage++;
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "count is : " + count, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
                    //cur.close();

                }
            } finally {
                cur.close();
                db.close();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "no Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}

 /*
   */

   /*
   buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            nextPage++;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "next page is"+nextPage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });*/




private void loadList(int number){
    ArrayList<String> sort = new ArrayList<String >();

    title.setText("Page "+(number+1+" of " +pageCount));

    int start = number * NUM_ITEMS_PAGE;
    for (int i=start; i<(start)+NUM_ITEMS_PAGE; i++)
    {
        if(i<data)
        {
            sort.add(String.valueOf(data));
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
      //  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), //android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,sort);
       // tablerow.setAdapter(adapter);
//implement table row in adapter
    }}

private void checkEnable(){
    if(increment+1 == pageCount)
    {
        buttonNext.setEnabled(false);
    }

    else if(increment == 0){
        buttonPrev.setEnabled(false);
    }

    else {
        buttonPrev.setEnabled(true);
        buttonNext.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
}
```

I want to know how can i change the page after no. of rows exceeds 30. I am unable to do pagination.
Currently i am using Sqlite and all the filled data is appearing on the first page.
I want to divide the data and want it appear in set of 30 after click of previous and next.

Comment: what prevents you to do pagination, are you getting errors, or simply don't know how to do because of lack of experience? please, clarify

Comment: Due to lack of experience i am not able to do so. I have tried various methods but till now i haven't been successful so want some help.

Comment: have you tried to make investigation yourself? there's a lot of information on StackOverflow ([here 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634523/how-to-show-paging-in-a-dynamic-tablelayout-in-android) and [here 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980510/how-to-create-a-pagination-for-dynamically-created-table-layout-using-set-visibl)), and here is some [tutorial](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-example/).

Comment: i have tried all this but i am not getting the desired result. any help would be appriciated.

Comment: I tried all this but couldn't figure out a method to do this. If somebody knows how to do paging for table rows when data size is dynamic please suggest me a way out.